# FFMpeg HLS to MXF video codec copy non monotonically increasing dts issue

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, hls, mxf

I am rewrapping an HLS stream as an mxf file.  The HLS is 1080p59.94 10bit 4:2:2.  The mxf is a video codec copy and an audio conversion to pcm. The stream has video timecode burn-in for me to watch the video frames. Here is the command

```
ffmpeg -i "https://myinput/index.m3u8" -f segment -timecode "01:01:01:00" -segment_time 600 -reset_timestamps 1 -c:v copy output_%03d.mxf
```

I get the following non-fatal error

```
"Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1"
```

The file is still created, however. In VLC the file plays correctly frame by frame. But in Adobe premiere when I play frame by frame I get video stuttering and I see the timecode burn in plays in a sequence like this... 3 frames ahead, then 2 frames back... so the frame sequence would be something like ;03 ;01 ;02 ;06 ;04 ;05 ;09 ;07 ;08

It's almost like Premiere does not know how to order the frames back together but VLC does. Any thoughts on how I might change the command to reorder the dts monotonically?

When I wrap to a .ts file I don't get this issue in Premiere, but I need MXF because Premiere can play an MXF file as a growing file.

Comment: I would need the input HLS package and the output MXF file.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann Here is an example stream
`ffplay -i https://547f72e6652371c3.mediapackage.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/out/v1/3fc62e3339d54d9786d176453584c594/index.m3u8 -live_start_index -1`

Here is an example output mxf I created.
https://testbucket-forstackoverflow.s3.amazonaws.com/Test_output_000.mxf